# How to reach the end of a scroll bar in appium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to automate scrolling of a horizontal bar,where the elements of the bar are dynamic and are getting fetched from an API.

Is there a way to automate it in appium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any element  or text in the bottom of page then you can use UiAutomator2.

add in desired capability 'UiAutomator2' if you are using appium.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

Now use below functions if you have element's id

```
 public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Use this if you have element's text.

```
public void scrollByText(String menuText) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + menuText + "\").instance(0));")); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you don't know any element in botton then you have to use screen size

```
public void scrollToBottom() {

      int  x = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
      int start_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.2);
      int end_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.8);
        TouchAction dragNDrop = new TouchAction(driver)
                        .press(PointOption.point(x,start_y)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                        .moveTo(PointOption.point(x, end_y))
                        .release();
        dragNDrop.perform();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Muzzamil. Unfortunately I don't know the last element at the end,it's being fetched from API and dynamic.
I've added the desiredcapability as you have suggested.

Comment: @lionxlamb I have edited post as per you requirement. Have a look on last function.

Comment: @Muzzamil Do I read your code right that you are assuming that scrolling down for **8 * driver.manage().window().getSize().height** would be the bottom? I don't think that is always true.
I would put the scrolling in a loop and stop scrolling as soon the Y-position does not change anymore.

Comment: @AndiCover 8 will be 80%  of height of screen so it will be almost bottom. Scrolling will be happen 20% to 80% of height. If we will put scrolling/function in a loop then in every iteration it will take screen width and height and calculate x, start_y and end_y so It will be dyamic if we invoke function in a loop.

Comment: @Muzzamil, Thanks for clarification. I thought driver.manage().window().getSize().height returns the height of the device screen and not the actual device.

Comment: @AndiCover Welcome 

Comment: @Muzzamil, sorry about my delay in response.I tried the last code snipped and following is the error.
`Coordinate [x=720.0, y=5424.0] is outside of element rect: [0,0][1440,2712] `
I think it is because the co-ordinates are wrong.I've seen the same way of calculating a screen by 80% and 20% in some other answers but I keep on getting `index out of bound` error.

Comment: For `x,start_y and end_y`  following are the co-ordinates I'm getting `720,5424,21696`  respectively.

Comment: @lionxlamb Thanks for cross check. I did a small mathematical mistake. To get 20% we have to multiply by 0.2 to full height while I was multiplying by 2 so its making height coordinate 2 times of height and obviously it will go outside of screen (Index out of bound so call). I have edited it and tried. Now it's working.

Comment: @lionxlamb Please accept it as answer if it solved your query. It will be helpful for community if someone is looking for similar question.

Comment: In case of handling with xpath how can we use it? Because UI Selector does not have xpath method.