# How to perform scroll in android native app with javascript

Tags: android, appium, scrollview, native

I am using appium and webdriverIO to automate android native app. I need to perform scroll down and i have used

```
ele.scrollIntoView(true) //this returns not yet implemented error
```

is there any other way to scroll down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find a way to perform swipe down by calling JsonWireProtocol api directly from my code. 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

here is my code

```
module.exports.scrollAndroid = function (ele) {
    console.log('driver.sessionID = ', driver.sessionId);
    while (!$(ele).isDisplayed()) { . //$(ele)=$(//xpath or any other attribute)
        this.scrollAPICall();
        driver.pause(3000);
    }

};
module.exports.scrollAPICall = function () {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("result status >> ", this.status);
        console.log("result text >> ", this.responseText);
    };

    url1 = `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/${driver.sessionId}/touch/flick`;
    xhttp.open('POST', url1);
    console.log("URL >> ", url1)
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
        xspeed: 10,
        yspeed: -100,
    }));
```

if you want to scroll up then give yspeed as + value. ex:100

Comment: Why so much headache when appium library is giving readymade function to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't used java script to scroll down. but I have already given a detail answer with different approach (by some text, element and screen size). Please have a look on it.

[How to reach the end of a scroll bar in appium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880178/how-to-reach-the-end-of-a-scroll-bar-in-appium/54881396#54881396)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Using UiScrollable is great approach.

Comment: Yes. its very helpful too.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve a scroll down by performing a Screen Swipe Up action. Implementation of swipe class can be found from Boilerplate project. The Gestures.js class has all required functions. Here is the link to [class](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/blob/master/tests/helpers/Gestures.js)

Please keep in mind that the swipe is performed based on the percentage. Once you implement this Gestures class you can then use it like below:

```
while(!element.isDisplayed()) {
      Gestures.swipeUp(0.5)
}
```

Comment: updated link to the [Gestures.ts](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/blob/main/tests/helpers/Gestures.ts) file