# Unable to scroll Horizontally in Appium using UiScrollable and TouchActions

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to scroll till the Gift Card option on Make My Trip Home Page and then Click it. So far I have tried below two approaches without success. I am also attaching the screenshot of the App Home Page for clear understanding.

Approach 1 : Using AndroidUIAutomator to scroll to particular element.

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
                + ".resourceId(\"com.makemytrip:id/rvHomePageIcon\"))"
                + ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"Gift Cards\")"
                + ".instance(0));"));
```

Result : This does not scroll but clicks on Homestays option on the app.

Approach 2:

```
WebElement eleOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Flights']"));
WebElement eleTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Gift Cards']"));
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(eleOne))
                .withDuration(ofSeconds(8))).moveTo(element(eleTwo))
                    .release().perform();
```

Result : This throws No Such Element Found exception as eleTwo is currently not in frame. I tried to tweak this approach and enter eleTwo as an element which is visible on screen just to see if the scrolling works and it did work. 
But Somehow I am not sure on how to handle it for elements which are not visible on screen.

I would like to scroll the top options list and then click on GiftCard which is the last option on top widget menu.

I am using AppiumDriver with Java-Client 7.3.0.

[image: IntialPosition]
[image: ScrollingTillGiftCard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, With uiAutomator2 (set scrollable as true):

```
public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can scroll Horizontal and vertical based on screen size with Touch Action. Here is sample code.

```
public void scrollHorizontally() {

      int  y = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 2;
      int start_x = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().width * 0.2);
      int end_x = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().width * 0.8);
        TouchAction dragNDrop = new TouchAction(driver)
                        .press(PointOption.point(start_x, y)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                        .moveTo(PointOption.point(end_x, y))
                        .release();
        dragNDrop.perform();
    }
```

I have written one detailed answer to scroll with different approaches. You can check here:

[How to reach the end of a scroll bar in appium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880178/how-to-reach-the-end-of-a-scroll-bar-in-appium/54881396#54881396)

Comment: Hi Muzzamil thanks for your response but still instead of scrolling it is still clicking the Homestay option.

Comment: @KovidMehta, I have added code for horizontal scroll based on screen size. you can call it before click. I hope it will work in one function call, but if you feel you need more scrolling just use while condition with target element's visibility. Hope it will help.

Comment: That doesn't work as well. The method is not doing anything on screen. Do I need to update something in it ?

Comment: No update is required. But it should work. Do you have recently updated  appium or selenium version. Is it throwing any error?

Comment: No it  is not throwing any errors. It just waits for few seconds maybe and then moves to execute next command. Selenium - 3.141.59 and Appium server v1.13.0

Comment: Appium dependency version?

Comment: Appium Dependency Version - 7.3.0

Comment: Check with selenium (3.14.0) and appium (6.1.0)

Comment: Hi Muzzamil, I was able to solve this with the above method. I think the issue was the co-ordinates I was referring to was wrong. I used the below line of code to make it work. In case of horizontal scroll it's important to have the Y co-ordinate as constant and vice-versa for vertical scrolls.                                                     
t.press(PointOption.point(x, y)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(x, y)).release().perform();

Comment: Yes. Because we are scrolling on width so x coordinate will be changed.