# How to validate the accuracy of touch actions for scrolling on a mobile device?

Tags: selenium, testing, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

My scenario is to scroll to somewhere in the middle of the page, to an element which is dynamic.
Now when I use touchAction using :-

```
TouchAction tc2=touchAction.press(PointOption.point(startX, startY)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY)).release().perform();
```

The amount of scrolling is inconsistent, sometimes it over scrolls and sometime it underscrolls.
Also we do not have a boolean return for touch action to know wheather it has actually worked or not.

Q1.How do we validate wheather or not TouchAction is working correctly or not?

Q2.Which is the best way to implement scroll for mobile devices using appium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good approach I have used. You can do scrolling to look a specific element with `UiAutomator2` OR scrolling till the `element` is visible on page.

Add in desired capability `UiAutomator2` if you are using `appium` as automation engine.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

Now use below functions if you have element's id, and index as 0 for there is one element on page.

```
public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There is more ways to do scrolling. You can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880178/how-to-reach-the-end-of-a-scroll-bar-in-appium)

Comment: What if I am not able to get elements to scroll to that specific element

Comment: Element to get specific element?? You want to say locator?

Comment: @adityarawat  If you have text you can scroll using text too or by coordinate.  Another way is using percentage of screen size now tell me what you need?

Comment: @adityarawat have you tried it. I have mentioned all solution in mentioned hyperlink in last line

Comment: @adityarawat glad to hear